Why is it that so many newly installed programs do not show up in the Menu?
Why is it that so many installed programs that do not show up in the Menu ?
I am using Ubuntu_Mate 24.04.
I try to use Synaptic Package Manager,but many programs are not listed.
When that occurs I have do a search for how to start the program.
I am willing to add programs to the Menu manually.

It's up to the mantainer of the package to decide whether to include an option to "run the program" from the menu or not, in that sense the answer to why is "because who mantains the package decided so"; command line utilities / applications almost never provide a way to start them from the GUI (I say almost because you never know, but I've personally never ever witnessed one, not that I recall at least), you're expected to just run them from the command line. You can however create your own .desktop files to start whatever using the menu

Actually, you can run programs in a semi_Gui by using scripts.(I am a retired chemist and I love to learn new things.)

This is strange - the question asks why something happens but the accepted answer makes no attempt to explain why that happens

Use a menu editing tool for MATE to add the apps to the menu manually. Alacarte is an easy-to-use menu editor for GNOME that can add and edit new entries and menus. It works with the freedesktop.org menu specification and should work with any desktop environment that uses the spec (including MATE maybe). If not, search in the App Center for an alternative menu editing tool for MATE.
